# Использование приватных (private) и защищенных (protected) полей

Tags: ооп

Если с использованием публичного типа полей мне все ясно - это то, что объект может предоставить для свободного доступа и модификации, чаще всего это реализуется через геттеры-сеттеры - то разницу между приватными и защищенными я не очень понимаю, точнее, не понимаю, как отделить границы использования одного от другого. Если очень грубо, то класс должен "светить" только необходимые вещи, чтобы не засорять текущую область видимости лишними деталями. И тут я и начинаю плавать: вот, допустим, у меня есть класс, реализующий действия с базой данных:

```
class SimplePdoWrapper
{
    /** @type PDO */
    protected $pdo;
}
```

$pdo - это ресурс, через который посылаются запросы к базе данных. Я должен объявлять его как protected или как private? Как понять, нужно ли предоставлять прямой доступ к этому полю отнаследованному классу? Я отлично понимаю фразу "closed for modification, opened for extension", но как только подожу на практике, у меня начинается ступор: если я скрою эти поля, будет ли это означать ограничение расширяемости?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Упрощённо говоря, придерживайтесь следующего правила: объявляйте приватным *всё, что можно*.

Вы не должны оставлять поле или метод доступными наследнику «на всякий случай», вы должны понимать, почему без него наследникам не обойтись. Конечно, «open for extension» — это правильно, но в принципе расширение функциональности должно быть возможно не заглядывая в «грязное бельё» текущей имплементации.

Если вы строите иерархию классов, вам придётся для начала её спланировать. Вы должны прикинуть, какие непубличные свойства/методы являются важными для расширения (их должно быть по идее совсем немного), а какие не нужны, порождённый класс вполне может обойтись официальными, публичными методами. Прокрутите в голове несколько вариантов расширения.

Возможно, с первого раза получится неоптимально, и придётся пересматривать структуру. С практикой придёт опыт.

Comment: @VladD вот и я так же думаю, что если сомневаешься, зачем это тебе надо, то в выносишь в private, а плохой кодер пусть плюется, это его его право.

Comment: @perfect: В конце-концов, всегда есть рефакторинг :)

Comment: @VladD, не, не хочу рефакторинг |:

Comment: @Etki: Мне приходится, достаточно часто :-\ Рефакторинг — это не так уж и плохо, если привыкнуть к нему.

Comment: @VladD я про то, что хотелось бы такие вещи сразу начисто писать (ну или максимально близко к тому). А так тут тут один проект целиком собирается уехать на рефакторинг.

Answer (score 2):

В многих случаях действительно очень сложно вначале решить, какие поля видимости дать для каждого метода (функции) и полей. Как распределять - приходит с опытом.

Когда мне нужно написать класс для какой-то работы, я тоже не всегда знаю, какую видимость дать для каждого поля. Поэтому делаю минимальную видимость. Если поле не будет использоваться вне - приватную, если будет - публичную. protected появляется тогда, когда появляется наследование.

Но некоторым полям обычно легко указать видимость. К примеру, если это ресурс (как в Вашем примере), то по умолчанию я бы делал его приватным. А также некоторые методы-обертки (для открытия и закрытия подключения, получения данных). А вот protected подобные поля делать не нужно. Максимум, что можно сделать, - это protected константный геттер.

Поэтому мой любимый совет - перестать ныть и писать код. По ходу написания кода будет понятно, как все сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Все, что попадает в public, считается интерфейсом класса, в эту часть попадает все, через что взаимодействует класс с внешним миром. Все, что относится к внутренней работе класса, помещаем в private секцию и обеспечиваем инкапсуляцию. Если вы знаете, что класс будет унаследован потомком и ему нужен доступ к private секции, "суем" это в protected. Я так всегда делал, и проблем не было.

Comment: @perfect, класс знает, что будет унаследован потомком только в том случае, если он абстрактный, и именно с выделением того, что может быть переопределено у меня и появляются проблемы.

Comment: @Etki например, в с++ любой класс может иметь потомки (это больше вопросы именно языка), а не только абстрактный - ведь архитектуру наследования продумываете именно вы, а не язык, как вы воспринимаете.

Comment: @perfect, 

> любой класс может иметь потомки

Я не про то, что он не может, а про то что ни одна реализация не должна полагаться на наличие или отсутствие потомков. Потому что это либо вводит обратную зависимость (не ту, которая DI) и класс перестает существовать в отрыве от дочерних реализаций, либо ограничивает расширяемость. Любой класс просто должен предоставлять интерфейс, как публичный, так и внутренний, для вероятных потомков (если класс не final, конечно), но это должен быть именно интерфейс, а не постеленная соломка для последующих реализаций. Вот с его выделением у меня и проблемы.

Comment: @Etki если б я сомневался, как вы, то я б засунул именно в private, а если б получил потомок от него, то уже не обращался к неизвестному мне (например, методу, который написал год назад). У класса есть интерфейс, через него идут все обращения к классу, и он самодостаточен сам по себе. Зачем лишнее выдумывать, что приведет к неизвестным последствиям. Как-то так.

Comment: @perfect это не лишнее. Завтра я пишу Библиотеку Года и выкладываю ее в открытый доступ, и там все в private, включая, допустим, метод получения данных из БД. Пользователи плюются и переделывают свои базы данных просто потому, что я не объявил этот метод как protected и они не могутпросто отнаследовать свою реализацию.

Comment: @Etki вот как раз выше я написал, что архитектуру продумываете вы сами, и дать вам доступ к этому методу другим разработчикам или нет, решаете вы. А чистый код (написанный за раз) редко написать приходится в идеале - это нормально.

Comment: @perfect, именно потому что я ответственный за свою архитектуру, я и хочу четко знать, как ее организовывать. Если б меня устраивало идти путем ошибок, я бы не создавал этот вопрос.

Comment: значит сделайте обе реализации классов или класс прослойку и ошибок не будет